# Can I use the TFS Object Model to interact with TFS via F#?

Tags: tfs, f#

I am looking for some quick ways to do some (more) complex queries across who has what checked out and things like that (eg. which files have >1 person checked out).

I have been learning F# over the last year or so and saw the potential to use both the functional aspects of F# to quickly create some useful and more complex TFS commands.

I was wondering if anyone else has done this, or have any ideas on how I would go about doing this.

PS: I am using TFS 2005.

Thanks

Russell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need the Visual Studio 2005 SDK to get the needed assemblies. The SDK also includes a few examples in C# you can use as reference, and some dokumentation. Neither is very good (IMHO) so you'll probably have to do some googling.

I wrote the following code as proof of concept, but it might help you to get started. Note this is written in VS2010 so you might have to use #I statements to reference the right assemblies.

```
#light
// #I @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\"
#r "Microsoft.TeamFoundation"
#r "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client"
#r "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client"
#r "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client"

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Net
open Microsoft.TeamFoundation
open Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
open Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
open Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client


type TeamFoundationClient(uri, credentials : ICredentials) =
    let server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection (Uri uri, credentials)
    let workitemStore = server.GetService(typeof<WorkItemStore>) :?> WorkItemStore
    let versionControlServer = server.GetService(typeof<VersionControlServer>) :?> VersionControlServer

    member this.ExecuteQuery wiql =
        workitemStore.Query(wiql) 
            |> Seq.cast<WorkItem>

    member this.GetWorkItem id =
        workitemStore.GetWorkItem (id : int)

    member this.GetChangeset changesetUri =
        versionControlServer.ArtifactProvider.GetChangeset (Uri changesetUri)

    member this.GetChangesets (wi : WorkItem) =
        let isChangeset (link : Link) = 
            match link with 
            | :? ExternalLink as link' when link'.LinkedArtifactUri.Contains("Changeset") -> Some (link')
            | _ -> None
        wi.Links
            |> Seq.cast<Link>
            |> Seq.choose isChangeset
            |> Seq.map (fun l -> l.LinkedArtifactUri)

    static member CreateCredentials (username : string) (password : string) (domain : string) = 
        (NetworkCredential (username, password, domain)) :> ICredentials
```

//Huusom

Comment: Thanks, that is a great start. :) I am using VS2010 too so this will make it even easier! I'll give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the Visual Studio 2005 SDK.  The needed assemblies are installed when the Team Explorer client is installed (or automatically along with VS2010 Ultimate).